# "Unique" is not defined

Tags: javascript, sorting, unique, defined

I am a beginning Google sheets script writer, though I've done javascript and coding for years.  I am trying to do some simple sorting on arrays, but can't get the UNIQUE or the SORT function to work.  Any reference to them and I get:

```
ReferenceError: "UNIQUE" is not defined.
```

I'm starting to think I am missing a library or module or something needs to be enabled in sheets.  I did enable the Google sheets API, through the Resources tab on the script editor.

Here is my script:

```
function fcnImportStockData() {
  var i=1;
  var arrStockSymbols = [];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");  

  // get last cell of the range
  while (sheet.getRange("C"+i).getValue() != "" ) {
    sheet.getRange("d15").setValue(i);
    i++;
  } 
  arrStockSymbols = UNIQUE("C1:C"+i);

}
```

On a side note, I couldn't get the function ISBLANK to work either, to simplify the While loop looking for the first blank cell in the column to set the range for sorting.

I think I am missing something simple or big picture.  I have scoured the web for similar situations, and found nothing much.

TIA!

Comment: I think this could help: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#getting_a_custom_function_from_the_add-on_store

Answer (score 0):

First, keep in mind that Google Sheets Script is nothing more then Javascript.

`UNIQUE()` is not a valid JS function, but it's a spreadsheet function that can be used inside a formula.

To use it, you must set a formula into some cell:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("X9").setFormula("=UNIQUE(C1:C" + i + ")");
```

Comment: So that would keep the action happening on the sheet instead of in the script.  I was planning to bring the contents of the sheet into an array, and do sorts and calculations, outputting to another array, eventually rewriting into cells on another sheet. I need Javascript methods of sorting an array then.